# Sites which provide FTP upload?

Tags: asp.net, ftp, file-upload, cdn, ftp-client

I'm working on a website which allows users from different part of world to upload files of size upto 500 MB.

The problems are:

1. As it is a HTTP transfer, it is slow.
2. As it is a HTTP transfer, it is non-resumable.

Users really suffer because of these two problems.

So, I want to find a FTP provider which can provide me the services meeting the following criteria:

1. To upload files with size upto 500 MB.
2. Anonymous upload.
3. If possible, in-browser solution i.e. using embed code.
4. It should be fast, may be, using distributed networks.

Please if any of you guys came across a situation like this or similar to this share the proivder name with their websites.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: You might consider breaking this into two questions... "What hosting provider allows large anon FTP uploads?" for SuperUser or *maybe* ServerFault.  And "How can I embed an FTP client in an asp.net site" for StackOverflow.

Comment: Smells like a serverfault.com question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an embedded Flash SWF file to do the upload.  It can upload the file in chunks using separate HTTP requests for each chunk, provide feedback to the user, and provide the ability to restart (as long as the page wasn't refreshed).

Google recently switched GMail to use an embedded Flash swf for attachment uploading.  It's much nicer than the old form post upload.